# Would it be safe to assume that TA and tutor are the same thing?

Tags: terminology, teaching-assistant, tutoring

I am currently an Australian studying at ANU. I have worked as a tutor for about a year and now I am about to apply for a Ph.D. program in the states. Since the US uses *TA (teaching assistant)* instead of *tutor* (at least my institution uses this term.) When listing my teaching experience, shall I use *TA* or *tutor* as a title? Are they the same thing?  I run labs or tutorials, I mark exams and assignments and so on.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience (at a US school), "tutor" usually refers to someone who gives one-on-one instruction.  Usually this is not part of the course itself, but is something that students who need help seek out independently (that is not to say that the school or department might not have some program for tutoring, but it's usually not considered "part of the course").

In contrast, a TA is someone who does grading, leads review sessions, helps proctor exams, or some other activity related directly to the course.  A TA often also has office hours for one-on-one help, but this is not their only duty.

Comment: In the U.S. and for math, graduate student TA's can also teach classes entirely on their own, but this is usually not until their 2nd or 3rd year, after the graduate student has had some reasonably successful experience as a TA leading recitation sections. Sometimes a graduate TA will begin teaching classes their first semester of graduate study if the graduate student has some prior teaching experience.

Answer (score 2):

I would not change the job title. List it as tutor and then provide a brief description of your job duties. In the US a TA can have duties ranging from only grading problem sets to independently running a class. When evaluating an application the admissions committee wants to know what you did and not what your title was.